# How to create custom material textfield in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am not able to customize the input label to be shown inside the text field. Below I have attached the sample mockup for your reference. How can I rectify my issue?
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: what is the red line? Do you want it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your label always at the top (even with empty textfield) then one way of doing it is to create your custom textfield widget and stack all your visuals there like this

```
    Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 60,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 3,
            left: 30,
            child: Text(
              'Email Address',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 30,
            bottom: 3,
            right: 30,
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'Enter email'),
              onChanged: (s) {
                text = s;
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: How to handle focus? Eg change border color when focus?